# Best RAD tools for building a sales ordering / invoicing web application

Tags: web-apps, web-development, invoicing

I am planning to develop a **web based invoicing application** for multiple users. It will be used by individuals to log and review their invoices. User data must be saved to a common database, but kept separate from other user logins (ie user data must not be shared / revealed to other users). I suspect I will need the following...

1.a login page / authentication

2.forms to enter a user's unique customers and items

3.a form for users to enter their invoices

4.solid reporting tools / dashboard capabilities

The current knowledge base is Microsoft (ie C#, SQL, .Net)

Can anyone advise the best RAD Tools / environment to achieve this outcome? Cheers!

I don't want to reinvent the wheel.  Surely there must be a suite of tools with solid authentication and reporting capabilities that will make this job much easier than otherwise.

Comment: Consider an open source platform as a starting point.  The first one here looks somewhat promising: https://github.com/search?l=C%23&q=invoicing&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93 Another option would be a ecommerce platform, even though you don't need many of the ecommerce features, it has pretty good invoice tracking features and ability to add them manually: http://www.nopcommerce.com/demo.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Telerik's ASP.net Controls](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx) in Visual Studio in the past to build a similar application(simpler though, not as complex). They should help aid and cut down development time. 
Implementing a business rules engine with workflows, will provide consistency and security. 
Telerik also has reporting  as does visual studio. If you design the database, you might be able to cut development time using Visual Studio's [LightSwitch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff851953.aspx) which could potentially speed up development tremendously

Answer (score 0):

You can try [WaveMaker](https://www.wavemaker.com). It is one of the most popular RAD tools out there for CRUD web applications. It generates responsive web apps but you can build hybrid mobile apps too. It is based on frameworks such as AngularJS, Bootstrap, D3JS (charting), Hibernate, Spring. You can drag and drop components (widgets) and visually design pages/screens with forms that are connected to a data source (db, REST API) with 2-way data binding. As far as authentication is concerned, it generates automatic login screens that can be hooked to LDAP, Active Directory, CAS or a custom database/service. You can then provide role-based access to different screens.

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest you a platform which is developed by Codejig https://www.codejig.com/en/builder/, they offer also free trial for testing. Hope my anwer will help